# VBScript inside HTA

Tags: html, scripting, vbscript, hta

I'm new to HTA and I want to use VBScript.

I have some HTML and I wanted to generate the computer name inside a table (as an example)

The big problem I'm running into is how do I retrieve the value from my function and place it inside the HTML?

```
<body style="font:12 pt arial; color:white; filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(GradientType=0, StartColorStr='#0080FF', EndColorStr='#00FFFF')" onresize="RestoreWindowSize()">

<div align="Center">

<span id="Update">&nbsp;</span>

<table border="0">
<tr>
    <td>Computer name</td>
    <td><div>Data I would like to generate</div></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
</table>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I understand my HTML is a little sloppy and i'm going to clean it up.
How can I get data from a function called ComputerName to appear within my  tags

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by traversing the DOM, just like JavaScript:

```
<html>
    <body style="font:12 pt arial; color:white; filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(GradientType=0, StartColorStr='#0080FF', EndColorStr='#00FFFF')" onresize="RestoreWindowSize()">

    <div align="Center">

    <span id="Update">&nbsp;</span>

    <table border="0">
        <tr>
            <td>Computer name</td>
            <td><div id="computername">Data I would like to generate</div></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    </div>
    <script type="text/vbscript">

        dim c: set c = document.getElementById("computername")
        c.InnerText = GetComputerName()

        function GetComputerName()
             ' do your computername lookup here
             GetComputerName = "Geoff"
        end function

     </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

here I've added an id to the `<div/>` that you're targeting, and used it get a reference to the element before setting its `InnerText` property.